# Is this robots.txt syntax with an empty "Disallow:" correct?

Tags: robots.txt

Today whilst improving my web crawler to support the robots.txt standard, I came across the following code at http://www.w3schools.com/robots.txt

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google 
Disallow:
```

Is this syntax correct? Shouldn't it be `Disallow: /` or `Allow: /` depending on the intended purpose?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Disallow:
```

Will allow everything, as will:

```
Allow: /
```

You're either disallowing nothing, or allowing everything.

Comment: Thank you, that makes everything much clearer now :)

Comment: WARNING: I added a robots.txt containing `User-agent: * Disallow:` then checked Google Search console 2 weeks later. The very day same day the robots.txt was created, Google stripped the site from its index. This file is almost useless unless you truly want to disallow a search engine. Don't add it just to make some SEO tool happy!

Comment: What about empty `Allow`, does that mean allow nothing?

Comment: `Allow:` is Google specific. Tell google it can access a page or subfolder even though its parent page or subfolder may be disallowed.